# Cannot execute gradle build in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, gradle

I create new Gradle project in `Eclipse Luna` but when I try to execute Gradle build through the Gradle plugin in eclipse I get an error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>
> > Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to
> >     point to the according directory.

The thing is `JAVA_HOME` is setted and running `gradle build` through the cmd is `OK`. I create two files in the same directory where build.gradle is located, there are:
`gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60
```

and `local.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60
```

UPD: When I try to delete and re-import that project, it works fine. When I click to the `build model` button it's also ok. But when I'm trying to execute build task, it doesn't workd.

Comment: I am having the same problem with eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this issue can be fixed.

1. Go to Eclipse-Luna menu Windows>Prefernces
2. Select Gradle>Arguments
3. Update Workspace JRE : to point to a **jdk instead of jre** as Gradle requires jdk for code compilation.

[image]

Here is where to update you installed JRE in eclipse. As you can see I have added a jdk.

[image]